# What is the reason for missing String#indexOf(str, fromIndex, toIndex)

Tags: java, string

I am trying to parse and deconstruct a `String` like `abc_value1` into its prefix and remaining content. Each part is separated by a delimiter, in this case the char `_`.

The prefix is always of a known type:

```
enum Type {
    ABC,
    ABCD,
    ABCDE
}
```

When trying to extract the type, `String` offers `indexOf(str, fromIndex)`, however, since all types are comple-time constant, the *minimum* and *maximum* length are also known in advance. Hence, i would prefer to use something `indexOf(str, fromIndex, toIndex)`, since it is guaranteed that the delimiter is in a particular range.

Internally, Java uses something like (`StringLatin1`)

```
@IntrinsicCandidate
public static int indexOf(byte[] value, int valueCount, 
                          byte[] str, int strCount, 
                          int fromIndex) {

        byte first = str[0];
        int max = (valueCount - strCount);
        for (int i = fromIndex; i <= max; i++) {
            // ...
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

So it´s probably not faster than to code it by hand. An alternative, to create a separate `#substring` also allocates a new object. Is there another way to implement this or would a proposal for `indexOf(str, fromIndex, toIndex)` make sense?

(Ignore the type lookup in a `Map` and casing for my example)

**Edit 1:** Some clarification, the primary use case is if *you have a long string and you want to stop searching at some point*.

Comment: What benefit does the "toIndex" offer? It finds the first occurance, so the "fromIndex" is the only relevant one. Unless you have a long string and you want to stop searching at some point.

Comment: @matt exactly, the *you have a long string and you want to stop searching at some point* is the point i wanted to make

Comment: In that case you split on the delimiter

Comment: It might make sense to implement `indexOf(char, fromIndex, toIndex)` if you are dealing with long Strings.

BTW, there is `indexOf(char` and `indexOf(String`.

Comment: We do not know the actual reasons for the decision, or even if such a method was ever considered.  However, the decision to include a method in an API is a judgment that balances "utility" versus the cost of writing and maintaining extra methods and corresponding test code for the lifetime of Java.  And also, a decision to add a method for a Java SE API is hard to reverse if the (future) consensus is that it was a mistake.

Comment: "since it is guaranteed that the delimiter is in a particular range." So you're saying this isn't necessarily true now?